# How to create cube using single mesh in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

To draw a cube which has 6 sides using libgdx need 6 meshes. But it increases time as per each mesh while rendering.

my code :

```
for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
{

    faces[i].setvertices(new float[] {x,y,z,color};
}
```

So, can we create a cube using single mesh rather than 6?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can create single mesh for cube. Check out
[SimpleVertexShader](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/gles2/SimpleVertexShader.java) test in libGDX tests. It uses [Shapes.genCube()](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/gles2/Shapes.java#L24) to create cube mesh.

Comment: Fixed links, libgdx moved to git